# How to create a airflow DAG to copy file from one S3 to another S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to create  airflow dag using python to copy a file one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket.

**My code**

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from utils import FAILURE_EMAILS

from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_copy_object import S3CopyObjectOperator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'email': FAILURE_EMAILS,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'S3_COPY_S3',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1
)

copy_step = S3CopyObjectOperator(
   source_bucket_key='source_file',
   dest_bucket_key='dest_file',
   aws_conn_id='aws_connection_id',
   source_bucket_name='source-bucket',
   dest_bucket_name='dest-bucket',
   dag=dag
)
```

Is this correct? Can you someone please verify

Comment: Alan Ma is right. It seems fine based on the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/s3_copy_object/index.html (as already mentioned given that strings for source_bucket_key etc. are just placeholders and you need to add "copy_step" in a new line at the bottom otherwise you just defined a task but it's not going to be ran).  Also since you have schedule interval set as none I assume it's triggered externally by another dag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values you provided are replaced with proper bucket names and s3 keys, the only thing you are missing the task_id for the S3CopyObjectOperator.

When instantiating an operator, you need to provide a unique task_id in the context of the associated DAG.